# Converting a form functional component to Formik form [using react hooks and redux]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have the following function component to post a comment, which works fine:

```
const PostCommentForm = (props) => {

    const [st_newCommentContent, set_newCommentContent] = useState('');

    const currentUserId = authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"];

    const onClick_postComment = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.postCommentEvent({
            Content: st_newCommentContent,
            ParentCommentId: null,
            UserId: currentUserId,
            DoesAgree: null,
            DateCreated: new Date(),            
        })

        set_newCommentContent('');
        //set_commentTextboxStatus(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form className="mt-2">
                <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Type your comment"
                    value={st_newCommentContent}
                    onChange={(e) => { set_newCommentContent(e.target.value) }}
                />
                <button
                    onClick={onClick_postComment}
                    className="btn btn-info pull-right m-1">
                    Post
                </button>
            </form>

            <div style={{ clear: 'both' }}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostCommentForm;
```

I want to build this form with `Formik` but I do not know how I should handle the submit and the state with Formik.

I can call `onClick_postComment` inside the `onSubmit` I guess, but then where should I put `setSubmitting(false)` to indicate submission is complete? Inside `onClick_postComment`, but how?

```
onSubmit={({ commentText}, { setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {

    setStatus();
    onClick_postComment();
})
```

Also, I do not know I should still use hook state with Formik. I could not find a clear example showing the use of Formik with hooks. I appreciate any help.

Comment: you can use ```onClick_postComment()``` to return a promise and after it resolves (inside ```.then()```) use to set ```isSubmitting``` to false, also, Formik includes a ```setSubmitting``` method. So you need not to handle the submitting state.

Comment: infact your case is the very case that fromik includes as an example [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial) have a look